# Не получается поставить row_width в цикле for, pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=5)
# Додайте кнопки для кожного доступного завданн
for task_number in available_tasks:
    emoji_number = ''.join(
        [
            f'{d}\u20e3'
            for
            d
            in
            str(task_number)])
    callback_data = f"task_n_{task_number}"
    button_text = f"Завдання {emoji_number}"
    btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
        text=button_text,
        callback_data=callback_data)
    keyboard.add(btn)
# Надішліть повідомлення з Inline клавіатурою
bot.send_message(
    message.chat.id,
    '<b> Оберіть завдання для заробітку:</b>',
    reply_markup=keyboard,parse_mode='html')
```

Comment: А что собственно не так? Тяжело что-то понять, поэтому можете пожалуйста добавить информации с скрином проблемы

Comment: 1 кнопка в ряду, а надо чтобы 5 было. извиняюсь что не обяснил

Comment: в плане у вас просто 5 кнопок вниз? если так, то это потому что вы добавляете их всех по одной(в каждом цикле добавление одной кнопки и поэтому вниз переходит).  Сохраните кнопки в массив и после этого добавьте сам массив в клавиатуру.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Только увидел ответ. Реально помогло! Респект